# Issues with Stateful processing in Apache Beam

Tags: java, state, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So I've read both beam's [stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) and [timely processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) articles and had found issues implementing the functions per se.

The problem I am trying to solve is something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802940/stateful-indexing-causes-pardo-to-be-run-single-threaded-on-dataflow-runner) to generate a sequential index for every line. Since I do wish to be able to reference the line produced by dataflow to that of the original source.

```
public static class createIndex extends DoFn<String, KV<String, String>> {
  @StateId("count")
  private final StateSpec<ValueState<Long>> countState = StateSpecs.value(VarLongCoder.of());

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c, @StateId("count") ValueState<Long> countState)  {

    String val = c.element();
    long count = 0L;
    if(countState.read() != null)
      count = countState.read();

    count = count + 1;
    countState.write(count);

    c.output(KV.of(String.valueOf(count), val));

  }
}

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://randomBucket/file.txt"))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new createIndex()));
```

I followed whatever I could find online and looked at the raw source code of ParDo and was not sure what needed to be done. The Error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ParDo requires its input to use KvCoder in order to use state and timers.
```

I looked up examples [here](http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/stateful-processing-apache-beam/read) and [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/StatefulTeamScore.java).

I realize this is a simple problem but due to lack of sufficient examples or documentation, I was unable to fix the problem. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so I continued working on the problem and after reading some source, I was able to resolve the issue. It turns out that the input for the `ParDo.of(new DoFn())` requires the input coming in to be of the form `KV<T,U>`.

Therefore in order to read the file and create an index for each line, I need to pass it through a Key Value Pair object. Below I added the code:

```java
public static class FakeKvPair extends DoFn<String, KV<String, String>> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    c.output(KV.of("", c.element()));
  }
}
```

And changed the pipeline to:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://randomBucket/file.txt"))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new FakeKvPair()))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new createIndex()));
```

The new problem that this raises is whether the order of the lines are preserved since I am running an extra ParDo function (that might potentially change up the order of the lines) prior to being fed to `createIndex()`.

On my local machine the order is preserved, but am not sure how that scales to Dataflow. But I will ask that as a different question.

Comment: Yes, states are stored by key. That's why the DoFn's input needs to be KV.

Comment: You can replace your `FakeKvPair` with the built-in `WithKeys` transform: `.apply(WithKeys.of(0).withKeyType(TypeDescriptors.integers())`.